# PHP PDO::PDO::FETCH_CLASS and parent class method access

Tags: php, class, loops, object, pdo

I'm trying to use the method defined within the parent class when looping through the objects returned from within the PHP PDO call fetchAll() with fetchMode PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE.

I have all of the properties set, but for some reason I cannot call the methods - here's what I've got:

```
abstract class Person {    
    protected $_table;    
    protected $Db;    
    public $id;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $email;      
    private $_password;
    private $_salt;     

    public function __construct() {
        $this->Db = new MySQL();
    }

    public function get($id = null) {
        $this->bind($this->Db->get($this->_table, $id));
    }    

    public function save() {
       // code goes here
    }

}    

class Client extends Person {

    protected $_table = 'users';    
    public $address_1;
    public $address_2;
    public $town;
    public $region;
    public $country_id;
    public $country_name;    

    public function __construct($id = null) {           
        parent::__construct();          
        $this->get($id);            
    }

    public function getAll() {
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM `{$this->_table}`
                ORDER BY `first_name` ASC";
        return $this->Db->getObjects(__CLASS__, $sql);
    }    

}

$objClient = new Client();
$users = $objClient->getAll();

if (!empty($users)) {
    foreach($users as $user) {      
        echo $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name.'<br />';           
        $user->telephone = '11111';
        $user->save();          
    }
}
```

When I run it I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save() in...

Here's the output of the var_dump() for one iteration of the $user:

```
object(stdClass)#6 (26) { 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "7"  
    ["first_name"]=> string(6) "First Name" 
    ["last_name"]=> string(4) "Last Name"   
    ["address_1"]=> NULL 
    ["address_2"]=> NULL 
    ["town"]=> NULL 
    ["region"]=> NULL 
    ["post_code"]=> NULL 
    ["country_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["country_name"]=> string(1) "United Kingdom" 
    ["email"]=> string(21) "email@email.com"    
    ["password"]=> string(100) "ff4a140e5c03ab5ssf5dce455594e485fasa5cb2cd22ce715c086" 
    ["salt"]=> string(9) "salt8877" 
}
```

Here's the getObjects() method from the MySQL() class:

```
public function getObjects($className = null, $sql = null, $params = null) {
    if (!empty($className) && !empty($sql)) {
        $params = is_array($params) ? $params : array($params);
        try {
            $this->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, $className);
            $statement = $this->query($sql, $params);               
            $result = $statement->fetchAll($this->_fetch_mode);
            $statement->closeCursor();
            return $result;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->exceptionOutput($e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `$users` have? paste the result of `var_dump($users)` here

Comment: Can you show us the getObjects function? I usually make this work by using: $pdo->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, new className());

Comment: Also its clearly its not using the class name, it creating new empty stdClass with the result columns

Comment: Yes - it returns the stdClass - I've just updated the ticket above.

Comment: Try using: $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, $className);